# .text section address range of position independent executable

Tags: c, linux, elf

I want the address of the .text section of a position independent executable. Using `readelf -S`:

```
Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
.text             PROGBITS         0000000000002700  00002700
       0000000000001672  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
```

I learn that it will begin 0x2700 bytes past where library was loaded into memory. But how can I get the load address of the executable?
Is there any other way to get the .text section address range during runtime (from the running program)?

Comment: What is the problem with the question?

Comment: I have found and presented a method which works for non position independent executables. Unfortunately it gives only partial result in my case. What else do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any other way to get the .text section address range during runtime (from the running program)?

Yes: you need to use [dl_iterate_phdr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html) and use `info->dlpi_addr` to locate the `PIE` binary in memory at runtime. The very first call to your `callback` will be for the main executable.